# Override Ionic Header with custom color

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to customize the color of a header with ionic ? 
By custom, I mean using a custom color and not one of the `bar-something` that are defined. 
I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive custom-dark">
</ion-nav-bar>
```

and in CSS:

```
 .custom-dark{
 color : #30393A;
 }
```

[Here is a codePen](http://codepen.io/NinaLysa/pen/JdjzjM)

I don't seem to be able to change the blue color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy fix is to use:

```
 .custom-dark{
    color : #30393A !important; // text
    background-color:blue!important; // for bg color
 }
```

This will overide the current css set..

I think its more appropriate to add to style sheet than in the html itself , as its easier for development , modifying and unnecessary bloating

Comment: Using only 'background-color:#30393A !important;' did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: The text is not working, at least for me. Is this still valid?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with SASS. If you haven't already type into terminal

```
$ ionic setup sass
```

You can then use the overrides inside the scss/ directory.

```
$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
```

I highly recommend using a CSS pre-processor for Ionic, they have a great lib with everything in variables for you.

Comment: I didn't test that, but it seems interesting. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have first run  ionic setup sass as mentioned in the answers, you need to search and identify the variable you want override on the file **_variables.css** and them you will override in **ionic.app.scss**.

For the bar-stable color i do find into _variable.scss :

```
$bar-stable-text: $button-stable-text !default;
```

And override in ionic.app.scss with:

```
$bar-stable-text:                 #FFFFFF !default;
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

add these line in your style.css under /www/css directory

```
.title.title-center.header-item {
        background-color:#F38023!important; // for bg color
        margin:0px!important;
        margin-left:0px!important;
        color: #ffffff!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override this Ionic Sass Variable in themes/variables.scss

```css
$toolbar-background:#FFFFFF;
```

[You can find other Ionic Sass Variable list here:](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

Override this Ionic Sass Variable in themes/variables.scss

```
$toolbar-title: #fff;
```